# Apple Discussions website not responding to clicks?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, websites, javascript

This is ironic, [Apple's Discussions website](https://discussions.apple.com/) is not working properly in the latest version of Safari (6.0.3) or Chrome (25).

Any link or button that I click on the page does not work.

Is this happening to anyone else? I've restarted each browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling JavaScript in Safari solved the issue:

[image]

It seems that Apple have **a bug in the JavaScript code** on their page.

Update — now it seems they are down for maintenance:

[image]

Comment: you crack me up :)